# Converting columns to character with sapply

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have a dataframe `test` whose columns are factors

```
class(test)
[1] "data.frame"

sapply(test, class)
  street     city    state 
"factor" "factor" "factor"
```

If I try to convert these columns to character with `sapply()` , something goes wrong and I not sure why

```
test <- as.data.frame(sapply(test, as.character))

sapply(test, class)
  street     city    state 
"factor" "factor" "factor"
```

I would expect the output to be all character columns.  Why are the columns not converting and how would one convert all factor columns to character?

Here is the test data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(street = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("12057 Wilshire Blvd", 
"15300 Sunset Boulevard", "17380 Sunset Blvd", "1898 Westwood Blvd.", 
"3006 Sepulveda Blvd.", "514 Palisades Drive"), class = "factor"), 
    city = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Los Angeles", 
    "Pacific Palisades", "Westwood"), class = "factor"), state = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CA", class = "factor")), .Names = c("street", 
"city", "state"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `sapply(data.frame(sapply(test, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), class)`

Comment: To clarify @d.b's comment, when you run `as.data.frame`, it carries a default argument `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, which is undoing the work you just did in `sapply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mutate_if`, this should also give you more control:

```
mutate_if(test, is.factor, as.character)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
test[] <- lapply(test, as.character)
```

or this:

```
test <- modifyList(test, lapply(test, as.character))
```

or this:

```
test <- replace(test, TRUE, lapply(test, as.character))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, it will apply the `as.character` function to each column of the dataframe. The `apply` function will return a matrix, so it just needs to be coerced to a dataframe by wrapping it with `as.data.frame`

```
test <- as.data.frame(apply(test, 2, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```