# Is there a way to specific colClasses using fread for one column and all the rest as character?

Tags: r, fread

Is it possible to set `colClasses` using `fread()` to read one of the columns in my csv file as `numeric` and read all other columns as `character`?

The problem is that if I only specify the type of this column using `colClasses = c("value" = "numeric")`, `fread()` automatically sets types for other columns but I need them read as `character`.

Comment: What classes do the other columns have? If you just want to prevent factors, you could use stringsAsFactors=FALSE. In the documentation of fread it says: 'colClasses in fread is intended for rare overrides, not for routine use.' and ' It won't downgrade a column to a lower type since NAs would result. You have to coerce such columns afterwards yourself, if you really require data loss.' Hope this helps.

Comment: @Florian `stringsAsFactors`  is FALSE by default for `fread`.

Comment: @Florian I have a problem in one column which contains the word False and True, `fread` converts it as a boolean column automatically while what I need is `character`. Moreover, I cannot specify the type for that column because I´m using this ´fread()´ in a loop, if some of the files doesn´t have that column there would be an error.

Comment: Do you know the other columns names? Why don't you just supply a named vector where the value column is numeric and all others are character

Comment: If you don't know the names ahead of time, you could read in the first 5 lines using `nrow=5`, pull out the names and then construct a character vector where all elements but the single desired element is "character". Something like `ifelse(names(dtTest) != "someName", "character", "numeric")`.

Comment: I use `mutate_if` to overcome such problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110199/converting-columns-to-character-with-sapply/45111653#45111653

Comment: Using `readr::read_csv`, you can specify column types with shorthand, `read_csv(file, col_types="iccc")` where `i` = integer and `c` = character.